# How to install on drive when drive c has not enough space Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I need to reinstall VS 2017 after it kills himself by Update. But now I have the problem that I cannot install it, because I dont have enough space available on drive C (need 15GB more). But I want to install it on drive D (free space 845GB).

Is there a way to say Windows 10. Ignore drive C you have to install on D?

best regards

Comment: It sounds like you need to deselect components you don't need.  You originally had it installed on the system partition so you obviously had enough space at one time.

Comment: It is not letting you select the location of installation. And on a seperate note, wouldn't it be better if you extend `C`'s space a bit more with **GParted** or something similar and then install it on `C` itself to avoid future conflicts.

Comment: @Biswa No, I can choose drive d as install folder. But the installation dont start, because I need so much space on C where I dont want to install...

Comment: @AzkerM I have enough space (~25GB free) on C, no need to extend. I always install programms or games on d.

Comment: So create an offline installation of VS in other drive. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706497.aspx)